# How to call a functional component in a class component?

Tags: react-native

I have a functional component to check if fonts have been loaded or not, I want to call it before the app render in `App.js` and if it's loaded give it a `state` called `loaded` but i don't know how can I do that because it's a class component, it's quite confusing to me:

Here's the functional component code:

```
    export default function Cache() {
      const [isLoadingComplete, setLoadingComplete] = React.useState(false);
      React.useEffect(() => {
        async function loadResourcesAndDataAsync() {
          try {
            SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
            await Font.loadAsync({
            /// fonts
            });
            finally {
            setLoadingComplete(true);
            SplashScreen.hideAsync();
                    }
                    }
    
             loadResourcesAndDataAsync();
                   }, []);
    
             return isLoadingComplete;
                     }
```

And here's my app.js component in which I want to call the `Cache` component:

```
    export class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          loaded: false,
        };
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          if (!user) {
            this.setState({
              loggedIn: false,
            });
          } else {
            this.setState({
              loggedIn: true,
            });
          }
        });
      }
      render() {
        const { loggedIn, loaded } = this.state;
    
        if (!loaded) {
          return null;
        } else {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just put your fonts in the componentDidMount like that

```
async componentDidMount(){
      await Font.loadAsync({
        'Montserrat': require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat.ttf'),
      }).then(() => {
      this.setState({fontLoaded: true})
    })
```

Comment: Thanks but this Cache file have multiple assets not just fonts i'd rather load before the app, if you know how can I call it in App.js please let me know